# What is wrong with my insertion sort program and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, insertion-sort

been cracking my head over this one for quite a while, trying to make a generic InsertionSort algorithm. 
However, debugging has failed me so I'm asking more experienced people, what is wrong with my code? 
Jared.

```
public static<E extends Comparable<? super E>> void sort( E[] a, int i, int j ) {
    int f; 
    int x; 
    for(x = i+1; x < j; ++x) {
        E temp = a[x];
        for( f = x ;  f >= i && temp.compareTo(a[j]) > 0; --f) {
            a[f] = a[f-1]; 
        }
        a[f] = temp; 
    }    
}
```

Comment: I've formatted your code for you, but in the future, please do this yourself. No sense making it more difficult for folks to understand your code and thus your question, right?

Comment: Correct! I've been looking all over the net for a code formatter or at least some sets of rules. 
Where could I approach them?

Comment: You could use most any IDE such as Eclipse to do it for you. Myself, I just posted your code in Notepad++ and formatted it by hand. I first highlighted it all, pressed shift-tab till all was flush left, and then indented blocks using the tab key.

Comment: You are doing `a[f] = a[f-1];` But you are not storing back `a[f]` in `a[f-1]` i.e. `a[f-1]=a[f]`. Am I mistaken somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the inner for loop, you're comparing the current element `temp` with `a[j]`, you should be comparing it with the previous element `a[f-1]` 
Change this

```
for( f = x ;  f >= i && temp.compareTo(a[j]) > 0; --f)
```

to

```
for( f = x ;  f >= i && temp.compareTo(a[f-1]) > 0; --f)
```

Also, if `i` is 0 and the condition for the loop is true, 
    `a[f]=a[f-1]` will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, so use `f>i` not `f>=i`

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate all the answers you guys have given me and thank you for helping me learn.
Jared.

Comment: That's correct, however if I have an array which is: A B C D E F G and i is 0 and j is 7, then my program will sort it out incorrectly.
Any pointers?

Comment: I tried it, with your code with my modification, it prints `[g, f, e, d, c, b, a]`, which seems correct. What was the output you expected?